# PhoneGap android : keyboard overlaps input field

Tags: android, cordova

I've an input field in a webview, when clicking on input the keyboard 
is shown but it comes over the input field. 
I tried putting `windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in androidManifest but 
still the same. 
When opening the same html page in device's browser everything is ok. 
Any ideas ?

Regards

**UPDATE:**

It doesn't have an XML layout, because I use the Phonegap framwork and the Activity extends DroidGap, and it doesn't have a `setContentView(xx.xml)` method.

```
public class TestActivity  extends DroidGap {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
        setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 30000);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try the suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205697/soft-keyboard-comes-over-the-edittext If it doesn't work please post your XML Layout source.

Comment: @Jan Gerlinger it didn't have xml layout.because I use the Phonegap framwork and the Activity extends DroidGap. and dont not have setContentView(xx.xml) method.   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
     setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 30000);
  super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I seem to have the exact same problem and added

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

to the AndroidManifest.xml file as you did. This did not work and finally somebody pointed out to use

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

instead. This works for me now. adjustPan seems to make more sense and adjustResize sounds wrong, but it does the job.

Answer (score 1):

In phonegap there are preferences for specific device. See configurations on this page: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml And the solution to change on config.xml is:

```
preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change preferences fullscreen to false

```
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
```

I tried and success!

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me with the answers combined from above:

```
<preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="stateVisible|adjustResize"/>
```

and:

```
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do it using with js and css codes. Thats working for me.

JS:

```
$("form input,textarea,select").focusin(function (){

    $(".scrollablefield").animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
    }, 600);
  });
```

css:

```
form{
    padding-bottom: 300px;
}
```