# Android keyboard overlapping input fields only scroll after type input

Tags: android, cordova, scroll, android-webview

I have the similar problem described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468842/phonegap-android-keyboard-overlaps-input-field). I've tried `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` but **it's not scrolled automatically scroll**; it's **only scrolling after type something into the input**. I need that it scroll input on top immediately after keyboard showing, so no need to type anything into the input before I can see the input.

The problem does not happen on Android 4.4, Android 5. Android 6 and onward it does happen. I use Cordova 6.

(Pictures are taken from [Android keyboard overlapping input fields, view doesn't scroll automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23913917/android-keyboard-overlapping-input-fields-view-doesnt-scroll-automatically) for demonstration purpose)

[image]
[image]