# input field is hiding virtual keyboard of mobiles overlaps the input filed when i am writing in input field on android device

Tags: html, css, input, android-softkeyboard, hidden-field

```css
.promo {
  width: 78%;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<h6>
  Have a Promo Code
</h6>
<br>
<span>
      <input type="text"   
class="form-control promo"  placeholder="Enter your Promo Code here">
          <span class="apply background"  >Apply</span>
</span>
```

---

THe input field text is hiding when keyboards is popinng on mobile screen in samsung phone
how can i prevent that keyboard dont hide the input field while wirting into it

Comment: Seee if this solves your issue  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23913917/android-keyboard-overlapping-input-fields-view-doesnt-scroll-automatically

Answer (score 0):

I think adjusting the height and width in your css file in promo class should help.
Please let me know if that worked.